# PHP Caching API json and using cached data when API down

Tags: php, json, caching

Let's say I have a php script that gets some json data through a url. How can I make my script so that it caches/saves the json response whenever the php script is loaded. Now whenever the API is for whatever reason unavailable or down then instead of using the API url the php script uses the cached json file instead.

Let's say I want the json responses saved in a directory called `/cache` for this.

Comment: do you know how to write a file or db?

Comment: @Dagon Yes, I have knowledge of mysql and writing to files.

Comment: well then should be all you need

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the following page on how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question that will likely get closed soon. But I'll add my thoughts anyway.

You would be better off separating this into two scripts.

1. One script runs on a schedule (cron job), fetches the json data from the remote URL, and updates the cache. This would ideally be a database, but it could be json files stored on the filesystem if you absolutely insist. If the remote url goes down, your scheduled job might miss updating the cache, but no big deal. It will update the cache the next time the url works.
2. The second script is your web page that strictly reads in the cached information from the database (or json files). It never calls the remote URL, and is never unavailable at all.

Beyond this, come back and post a new question when you have a specific issue, have attempted a solution, and can show your code.

Comment: don't encourage bad questions

Comment: @Dagon I'm a beginner myself, and can appreciate when someone will at least gently point me in the right direction. Hopefully I have helped the guy get going. How that could be a bad thing and worthy of a downvote is beyond me.

Comment: Thanks for getting me going and I appreciate it, I will mark it as correct seeing as you are one of the few members I see who help beginners. Thanks!

Comment: @ShivamPaw You're welcome!

Comment: @Dagon Strange that you spend so much time criticizing others for trying to help. If you don't like the question, flag/vote (as I'm sure you did) and then just move on for crying out loud.

Comment: Also you need to implement cache expiration date. I'm coming from Google Search for this question.